# Can't properly animate bootstrap 5 collapse element created via js

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

My goal is to create a collapse element when the form data has been processed by the server, to notify the user whether the data was successfully sent to the server or an error occurred.

```js
function sendForm(event, form) {
    const wrapper=document.createElement('div');
    wrapper.setAttribute('role', 'alert');
    wrapper.classList.add('alert', 'alert-dismissible', 'alert-success');
    wrapper.innerHTML='<span>Success!</span><button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert"></button>';
    form.prepend(wrapper);

    const bsWrapperCollapse = bootstrap.Collapse.getOrCreateInstance(wrapper);
    bsWrapperCollapse.show();
    setTimeout(() => {
        bsWrapperCollapse.hide();
    }, 4000);
    setTimeout(() => {
        wrapper.remove();
    }, 7000);
    form.reset();

    event.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <main class="container-fluid my-5" style="max-width:300px">
        <form action="#" method="post" onsubmit="sendForm(event, this)"> 
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">My form submit btn</button>
        </form>

        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
            Button with data-bs-target
        </button>

        <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
            <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-success" role="alert">
                <span>Success!</span>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I added two implementations to the test html - the first button calls my implementation, which is in the form and when it is pressed, data should be sent, but the animation of appearing and hiding is jerky. The second button is taken from the bootstrap documentation, with the correct animation, which is what I want to achieve in my implementation using js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I figured out how I can make the animation normal without even checking the answers here. I noticed that the alert container in the html code is wrapped in another container. But when I created the alert via js, I didn't wrap it. After I wrapped this element, the animation worked as it should. [@Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4110826/nick) suggested that the animation doesn't work as expected due to the lack of a `collapse` class, but I tested his code without it and the animation still works. The reason the animation works correctly is that he wrapped my code in a container via innerHTML, essentially doing the same thing I did. Here's what I ended up with.

```js
function sendForm(event, form) {
    const alert=document.createElement('div');
    alert.setAttribute('role', 'alert');
    alert.classList.add('alert', 'alert-dismissible', 'alert-success');
    alert.innerHTML='<span>Success!</span><button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert"></button>';

    const alertWrapper=document.createElement('div');
    alertWrapper.append(alert);
    form.prepend(alertWrapper);

    const alertWrapperCollapse = bootstrap.Collapse.getOrCreateInstance(alertWrapper);
    alertWrapperCollapse.show();
    setTimeout(() => {
        alertWrapperCollapse.hide();
    }, 4000);
    setTimeout(() => {
        alertWrapper.remove();
    }, 7000);
    form.reset();
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <main class="container-fluid my-5" style="max-width:300px">
        <form action="#" method="post" onsubmit="sendForm(event, this)"> 
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">My form submit btn</button>
        </form>

        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
            Button with data-bs-target
        </button>

        <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
            <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-success" role="alert">
                <span>Success!</span>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyway, I marked [@Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4110826/nick)'s answer as helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the element created in js haven't  the `collapse` class, the transition is applied only if the element has `collapse` class.  I modified the code , I added  the class `collapse` to the wrapper and added the alerts classes to a div inside the wrapper element.Now it seems the animation works properly

```js
function sendForm(event, form) {
    const wrapper=document.createElement('div');
    wrapper.setAttribute('role', 'alert');
wrapper.classList.add("collapse");
    wrapper.innerHTML='<div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-success"><span>Success!</span><button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert"></button> </div>';
    form.prepend(wrapper);

    const bsWrapperCollapse = bootstrap.Collapse.getOrCreateInstance(wrapper);
    bsWrapperCollapse.show();
    setTimeout(() => {
        bsWrapperCollapse.hide();
    }, 4000);
    setTimeout(() => {
        wrapper.remove();
    }, 7000);
    form.reset();

    event.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <main class="container-fluid my-5" style="max-width:300px">
        <form action="#" method="post" onsubmit="sendForm(event, this)"> 
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">My form submit btn</button>
        </form>

        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
            Button with data-bs-target
        </button>

        <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
            <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-success" role="alert">
                <span>Success!</span>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```